# Javascript WYSIWYG Logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've searched SO for similar questions, but it seems that they are all wrapped up in just making a div editable using `contenteditable="true"`.

I am curious about the most efficient way to keep track of all the formatting tags added to a document.  Just wrapping / unwrapping selected text with jQuery seems to corrupt the document after a few edits because of broken overlapping tags.

Would the correct approach be to separate all characters into an array, work out a logic to add / modify / remove tags at positions defined by `window.getSelection()`, and then render an output version to load into the editable div?  Or is there a better solution?

Comment: If I understand what you're getting at, this is *way* too broad for SO. If you want to know how this could be implemented, take a look at [CodeMirror](https://github.com/codemirror/codemirror), or tinyMCE, or CKeditor, etc...

Answer (score 1):

It may be unnecessary to wrap elements in tags manually with javascript / jquery.  I've been reading about `execCommand()` and it seems to be widely supported.  This would allow for most formatting options found in WYSIWYG editors, color, font size, family, adding links, etc...  I realize that my initial question was a little broad, but perhaps this will point someone else in the right direction as well...

Examples:

```
document.execCommand('bold', 0);
document.execCommand('forecolor', 0, '#ff0000');
document.execCommand('fontSize', 0, '7');
```

Works in chrome / firefox / safari, not sure about IE yet.  The above bold example demonstrates how the browser keeps track of the existing formatting and can toggle the style on/off.